# Svelte SMUI, retrieve theme colors in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, sass, sveltekit

I am using SMUI with svelte and in SCSS I have set the theme colors:

```scss
@use 'sass:color';

@use '@material/theme/color-palette';

@use '@material/theme/index' as theme with (
  $primary: #ef8611,
  $secondary: color.scale(#8aace1, $lightness: 90%),
  $surface: #333,
  $background: #fff,
  $error: color-palette.$red-900
);
```

The value of `$primary` should then then be stored in bare css variable `--mdc-theme-primary` but it seems not to be...

The Question is simple:

**How can I get the color value of `$primary` from scss to JavaScript ? is it possible ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SCSS Theme File:

```scss
    // bare css to scss
    :root {
      --mdc-theme-primary: #ef8611;
    }
    
    @use '@material/theme/index' as theme with (
      $primary: var(--mdc-theme-primary)
    );
```

```scss
    // SCSS to Bare CSS
    @use '@material/theme/index' as theme with (
      $primary: #ef8611
    );

    :root {
        --mdc-theme-primary: #{theme.$primary};
    }
```

```scss
    // To use the variable in css
    button {
     background-color: var(--mdc-theme-primary);
    }
```

In Javascript:

```js
    const primaryColor = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--mdc-theme-primary');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Can I actually do the opposite ? first in SCSS and then Bare CSS ?

Comment: Yes, you can define your theme colors in SCSS and then export them to Bare CSS variables

Comment: I am not very familiar with SCSS, should I do : `--mdc-theme-primary:  theme.$primary;`  ?

Comment: 1. file ($primary: #ef8611;
:root {
    --mdc-theme-primary: #{$primary};
}) 2.file (button {
 background-color: var(--mdc-theme-primary);
})

Comment: Ok, the syntax is hard to guess, thanks a lot, could you update your answer so next ones can find that more easily ? Thanks a lot.
Actually the correct answer was : `--mdc-theme-primary: #{theme.$primary};` because `$primary` is inside `theme`

Answer (score 1):

```js
getComputedStyle(document.documentElement)
    .getPropertyValue('--mdc-theme-primary');
```

Comment: Ok, so I think i do not have that variable set up. it just gives me ''. Is there a way i set it directly in my theme ? I should be able to do it manually right  ? (e.g.  `setVar('--mdc-theme-primary', $primary)`

Comment: document.documentElement
    .style.setProperty ('--mdc-theme-primary',"#AAA");